# How to fix height of row of kendo grid

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my Kendo Grid I have a column which have html values. While displaying it increases the height row of that grid.

How can I ensure data will be displayed in single row whatever the value is.

Click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nbkx010c/2/) for the fiddle.

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { title: "Name", field: "name", encoded: false }
  ],
  dataSource: [ { name: "<br>Jane Doe</br><br>Lespie Knope</br><br>Ron Swanson</br>" } ]
});
```

```css
.k-grid tbody tr {
        width: 50px;
    }

    .k-grid td {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    <div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: How are you wanting to display the data? Like this `Jane Doe, Lespie Knoper, Ron Swanson`?

Comment: Have you tried without the breaks? `htmlname: "Jane Doe, Lespie Knope, Ron Swanson"`

Comment: I don't want to change the data. I just want to show user the first row.

Comment: It's just an example. In real life scenario in this column I have full html code like email templates.

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to solve the problem using template.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { title: "Item", field: "item", template: "<div style='height: 25px;'>#= item # </div>" }
    , { title: "Name", field: "htmlname", template: "<div style='height: 25px; overflow-y:scroll;'>#= htmlname # </div>" }        
  ],
  dataSource: [ { item: "11MPRICE", htmlname: "Jane Doe<br>Lespie Knope</br><br>Ron Swanson</br>" }
              ]
});
```

Check the dojo [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/IrituH).